# Go to symbol in workspace in specific category

Tags: visual-studio-code

The "Quick Open" dialogue has:

- "Go to symbol in workspace" (`#`)
- "Go to symbol in editor" (`@`)
- "Go to symbol in editor by category" (`@:`)

Why is there no "go to symbol in workspace by category? Is there any alternative approach? It's quite annoying in cases e.g. when you want to go to a types definition but you first need to wade through many variables with the same name.